# PHP Singleton Pattern for mysqli Wrapper

Tags: php, class, oop, singleton

I'm having an issue with the PHP singleton pattern, specifically with regards to implementing a mysqli wrapper.

```
class DbHandler 
{

    private $mysqli;
    private $query;
    private $results = array();
    private $numRows = 0;

    public static $instance;

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (!isset(self::$instance)) {
            self::$instance = new DbHandler;
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function __construct() {
        $this->mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "improved_portal");
        if ($this->mysqli->connect_error) {
            die($this->mysqli->connect_error);
        }
    }

    public function query($statement) {
        if ($this->query = $this->mysqli->query($statement)) {
            foreach ($this->query as $value) {
                $this->results[] = $value;
            }
            $this->numRows = $this->query->num_rows;
            return $this;
        }
    }

    public function getResults() {
        return $this->results;
    }

    public function getNumRows() {
        return $this->numRows;
    }

}
```

When I go to utilise the class in other objects, I seem to have an issue with the results. Instead of creating a new object each time with unique $results, it seems I am creating copies of the initial object. For example...

```
$object1 = DbHandler::getInstance();
$object1->query("SELECT * FROM table_a")->getResults();

$object2 = DbHandler::getInstance();
$object2->query("SELECT * FROM table_b")->getResults();
```

$object2 contains results from both queries, which is obviously not what I expect. The query function clearly loops through the results of the second query, and appends these to the $results property of the first object. How should I call a new instance of the DbHandler class so that each object contains unique properties?

Comment: You should make your `__construct()` method and `$instance` property private and only use static `getInstance()` method of your class to create an object.

Comment: `$this->results` must be __cleared__ every time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all - this is not singleton pattern. As your `__construct` is public I can do this:

```
$conn1 = new DbHandler();
$conn2 = new DbHandler();
$conn3 = new DbHandler();
```

To prevent this - `__construct` must be protected/private.

Second - everytime you call `query()` from the same object, this function add results to `results` property. And this `results` property is used for all queries without clearing. Surely, it will hold all previous values. Function should be rewritten like:

```
public function query($statement) {
    // clear result from previous function call
    $this->results = array();

    if ($this->query = $this->mysqli->query($statement)) {
        foreach ($this->query as $value) {
            $this->results[] = $value;
        }
        $this->numRows = $this->query->num_rows;
        return $this;
    }
}
```